# JavaSscript object array is not showing the expected value on using map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am basically getting the URL details from an external API and updating my state using `this.setState` in React, but now when the state is changed. I have used map on the JavaScript array, but it does not seem to have updated the expected URL. Rather it has the initial data.

Below is the code snippet I used in the `render()` function.

```js
console.log("output 1", this.state.blogData);
const blogDetails = this.state.blogData.map(data => {
    console.log("output 2", data);
    return (
        <Col key={data.id} xs={12} sm={4} className="person-wrapper">
            <Blogs
                key={data.id}
                content={data.content}
                title={data.title}
                imagelinksm={data.url1}
                imagelinklr={data.url2}
            />
        </Col>
    );
});
```

In the console output 1 has a different URL compared to output 2. I'm not sure if the map is causing the issue, although it's an array.

[image: output 2 image]

```js
» {id: 1, name1: "fligtsm.jpg", name2: "flight.jpg", url1: "N", url2: "N", ...}
    content: "<p>The month of January 2015, brings with it the news that Spice Jet...</p>"
    id: 1
    name1: "fligtsm.jpg"
    name2: "flight.jpg"
    title: "An Unanticipated Journey By Air"
    url1: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/portfolio-366c2.appspot.com/ ..."
    url2: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/portfolio-366c2.appspot.com/ ..."
    › __proto__: Object
```

I am able to notice that the first line in the above output that shows the expanded JavaScript object has a different url1 and url2 compared to the below, so because of this whenever I do a data.url1 I get "N" rather than the actual URL. Do you have any clue why this happens?

Comment: Can you at least take the time to lean up your code, show us the full console log, and what the `data` should look like?

Comment: I have read this 3 times now....still not able to figure out what your question is?

Comment: the object that i got in console seems a bit contradictory, since the value that i can see before expanding is different from the one that i got after expanding. Refer the above image. The first line has url1 and url2. But the same keys have different value inside. Why does this happen? Am i clear now? @HemantParashar

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
  const { blogData } = this.state;
  if(!blogData) return <p>Nothing...</p>

  return <>{ blogData.map(data => {
                                console.log('output 2', data)
                                return (
                                    <Col key={data.id} xs={12} sm={4} className="person-wrapper" >
                                        <Blogs key={data.id} content={data.content} title={data.title} imagelinksm = {data.url1} imagelinklr = {data.url2}/>
                                    </Col>
                                )
                            })
  }</>
}
```

reading a messy code is not fun.